# In xcode 11.4.1 I get this error "Use of unresolved identifier" for an image which is in assets folder, why is that?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let canoaimageview: UIImageView = {
        let imageview = UIImageView(image: canoa) //ERROR Use of unresolved identifier 'canoa'

        imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       return imageview
}()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()


    view.addSubview(canoaimageview)
    setupLayout()
    }

    private func setupLayout() {
    canoaimageview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    canoaimageview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    canoaimageview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    canoaimageview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    }


}
```

//an attached image is included showing the error and assets folder

[image]

Comment: what is `cona` sir ?

Comment: Canoa is the name of the image @jawadAli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an UIImage first to assign it to imageView like this

```
    let canoaimageview: UIImageView = {
        let imageview = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "canoa")) //ERROR Use of unresolved identifier 'canoa'
        imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       return imageview
}()
```

Comment: I can finally see the image when I build&run it but now theres two images on top of each other. A smaller one is on top

Comment: try it now .. and make sure you are adding just one .. either from storyboard or from code